# showing $E(X_{(i)}| \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i)=1.8E(Z_{(i)})$

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

suppose 5.5,3.5, 2.5,4.5,2 be a random sample from of gamma distribution with parameters of $ \beta,\alpha=2$. if $Z_{(i)}$ be i-th order statistic a random sample of size 5 from $\Gamma(2,1)$, how can I show $E(X_{(i)}| \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i)=1.8E(Z_{(i)})$